# Android. NDK. How to log calling destructor of global variable?

Tags: android, c++, static, android-ndk

As we all know android doesn't unload *.so after close application. I had found the solve by adding "exit(0)" at the end, that is solved problem, but I wanna know exactly that all are OK.

The code is work fine as expected after solving the problem:

```
static int value = 0;

// In android_main
LOGI("value = %d", value); // always print 0, but not 1 after second run of
// application as it was without "exit(0)" at the end
value = 1;
```

I wanna to test that on class like:

```
class A {
  A() {
    LOGI("Constructor");
  }
  ~A() {
    LOGI("Destructor");
  }

statis A a;
```

In such way prints only "Constructor".
Maybe because of destructor is calling after when LOGI isn't working more for application that will be closed ?
Question: why LOGI in destructor isn't working? According to first example on top destructor is calling really.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't unload a .so after closing the application.  Do you mean after finishing the activity?  It shouldn't-  if you need that, put a JNI call to deallocate any variables and call it in onDestroy or in finish.  If you mean it doesn't unload and reload after actually ending the process-  you're wrong.

Comment: Yes, I mean after finishing the activity. I wanna dealocate not variables, but singleton and therefore i need android calls the destructor of static variable aftef finishing activity.

Comment: Then don't kill or exit the process - that bulk de-allocates everything in the kernel.  If you really want to dispose of your singleton, remove all references then garbage collect it or invoke its destructor, as appropriate to its nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not only pointless, but quite possibly counterproductive.  If android wants the memory utilized by your process, it will terminate the process to reclaim it; if it doesn't, it won't.

To specifically address your question, killing or exiting a process **does not invoke destructors**, it merely terminates execution and the kernel bulk-releases all memory and (conventional) resources.

Do not try to second guess the system, as that can frequently result in killing a process only to have android immediately restart it.  Further, it can allegedly cause problems with a few Android IPC resources (like the camera) which may not be freed up when the process of a utilizing application unexpectedly dies.

Comment: How can I create a singleton then?

Comment: In the usual way - create a global static object only if it does not already exist.  That has nothing to do with this, and if truly unfamiliar belongs in its own question - though one that probably already has duplicates here.